# Convert c# collection list to ObjectResult<type>

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, collections

How can we convert a C# collection list to ObjectResult

I have a requirement where I have to use `GetNextResult` method of EntityObjects.

I have to use `GetNextResult` method, but currently it is in IEnumerable. This I want to convert into ObjectResult and then make use of `GetNextResult` method.

code

```
var res0 = _testDataProvider.GetTests(active, real, date); //returns IEnumerable<class>
var res1 = res0.GetNextResult<classname>(); //wants to use this method as we are doing the migration from entity to dapper
```

Comment: What is `ObjectResult<T>`?  What does `GetNextResult<T>()` return?

Comment: `ObjectResult<T>` is an asp.net return type, usually created in a `Controller` by calling `Ok(...)`. It's up to you how you want to create the single argument object or what type it is.

Comment: public virtual ObjectResult<TElement> GetNextResult<TElement>(); // from System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I'm aware of that one, but there's no ASP.NET tag on the question, so it could be anything.

Comment: GetNextResult is used to get the next result of a procedure. I am not sure if you actually have a procedure in res0. Here you can read up how to use the method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets

Comment: @Patrick, procedure result is in res0